# jMeter Multiple HTTP Requests

Tags: jmeter, atomic, stress-testing

I want to test a fully functioning website for load using a constant, known number of users - to that end I'm trying to recreate the "Retrieved All Embedded Resources" functionality for a web-page, only manually, because I really don't know if it fetches all resources grabbed by JS. So the first question is - how do I check to see what these subsequent fetches retrieve?

Second question is - how do I make the multiple requests atomic, like "Retrieve All Embedded Resources"? I need to use "Constant Throughput Timer" for making sure the number of vusers is constant, but:
When using "Retrieve All Embedded Resources", this counts as one request, and one thread handles it right (hopefully, again - can't tell what goes on beyond the scenes)
When using a recorded session with numerous elements, each element is one action and occupies the queue (counts as 1 sample for Constant Throughput Timer). Therefore, it's not atomic.

I guess I can count the elements and define them as number of samples for throughput per minute, but this won't do in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, jmeter does not execute any javascript in the pages retrieved. Clicking "Retrieve all embedded resources" does the following if you check the documentation:

Tell JMeter to parse the HTML file and send HTTP/HTTPS requests for all images, Java applets, JavaScript files, CSSs, etc. referenced in the file.

So it will check the current sample for any references and retrieve those, but it will not run any scripts that are retrieved.

If you want to check which resources jmeter is actually retrieving you could run for example Fiddler to check which requests are being made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Transaction Controller](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) to consider all embedded resources requests and master request as one sample, aggregate time will be logged and reported.

Comment: While this helps log the exact time of each "whole page", it still doesn't help with making a "whole page" a singular action. To elaborate - if a Constant Throughput Timer is set to 1 sample, and 1 thread is created, then the Transaction Controller is still not considered a singular sample as far as CTT is concerned.
I might be looking at it all wrong. I have a number of users accessing the landing page we would consider optimal. I figured CTT is a great way to control the amount of users, but that's restricted to number of literal samples, not "whole pages".